# Squirrel SQL mac lag when typing codes

Tags: sql, teradata, squirrel-sql

My screen lags very badly when I type my sql codes in the Squirrel interface. When I scroll up or down the page the interface also lags in and out. It becomes very hard to type code if it is more than 10 lines.

I have tried reinstalling Squirrel and my Teradata ODBC drivers.

Any other possible fixes?

Comment: I think it might have to do something with my Java drivers. Does anyone know how to update Java drivers for Squirrel on Mac?

Comment: You simply overwrite the existing `terajdbc.jar` and `tdgssconfig.jar` files. The location can be found in *Change Driver -> Extra Class Path*

Comment: The JDBC driver has no influence on the speed of scrolling. You should rather check if you can update your Java version (but then Java and Mac don't really go well together...)